# Automating pagination with PHP

Tags: php, json, pagination

Currently I'm using this piece of code to paginate a parsed JSON File

```
if ($_GET['page'] == 3){
     $x = 12;
     $y = 16;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 2){
     $x = 6;
     $y = 11;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 1){
     $x = 0;
     $y = 5;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 4){
     $x = 17;
     $y = 21;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 5){
    $x = 22;
    $y = 27;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 6){
    $x = 28;
    $y = 33;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 7){
     $x = 34;
     $y = 39;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 8){
     $x = 40;
     $y = 45;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 9){
     $x = 46;
     $y = 51;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 10){
    $x = 52;
    $y = 57;
 } elseif ($_GET['page'] == 11){
     $x = 58;
     $y = 63;
 }
```

then I've got a while loop which runs while `$x <= $y`

Can this be achieved using less code?

Thanks

Comment: why some pages y - x = 4 and some others y - x = 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the same number of rows in each page, something like this will work... Syntacs might be wrong, havent written PHP code for a long time  now

```
 /* Some variables to help  calculating*/
 $RowsPrPage  = 5;
 $PageNumber = $_GET['page'];

 /* Calculating $x and $y*/
 $x = $RowsPrPage * ($PageNumber-1);
 $y = $x + $RowsPrPage -1;
```

Result from fomula:

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 1  x = 0  y = 4

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 2  x = 5  y = 9

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 3  x = 10  y = 14

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 4  x = 15  y = 19

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 5  x = 20  y = 24

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 6  x = 25  y = 29

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 7  x = 30  y = 34

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 8  x = 35  y = 39

RowsPrPage = 5   PageNumber = 9  x = 40  y = 44